# (Rails) How do I get around the STI null fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I create a model with simple characteristics:

```
class CreateWingedThings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :winged_things do
    t.integer :number_of_wings
    t.integer :species
    t.integer :air_speed_velocity
    t.boolean :laden, :default => false
  end
end
```

But now I want two specific types of `WingedThing`, with their own distinct characteristics:

```
class CreateBats < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :bats do
    t.integer :echolocation_volume
    t.string :snout_type
  end
end

class CreateBirds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  create_table :birds do
    t.string :beak_size
    t.integer :number_of_feathers
  end
end
```

This is a simple enough thing to do with STI - Have `Bat` and `Bird` inherit from `WingedThing`:

```
class Bat < WingedThing
```

(Bonus question: How does this look in the DB? Do I have a `WingedThing` row generated for every `Bat` and for every `Bird`? That's my understanding of it, but please correct me if I'm wrong.)

(Following from this possibly mistaken understanding) But what if I wanted, say, a `FlightlessBird`? `air_speed_velocity` would be a meaningless field, and it would be rather unethical to burden it; all instances of `FlightlessBird` would contain null entries for `laden` and for `air_speed_velocity` in the DB rows generated for the corresponding `WingedThing`. This is more data than I need and doesn't lend itself to scalability, but I also don't want to remove the fields entirely since at least two other models depend on them.

**tl;dr** What I'd like to be able to do is have `Bird` and `Bat` be able to access the characteristics common to both, while having `FlightlessBird` have *some* characteristics of the same parent table but without generating null fields in the database.

What's the best way to model relationships like this, to make sure I get the slimmest DB possible?

Comment: Why migrations inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` and not from `ActiveRecord::Migration`?

Comment: Good question. Fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, for STI you don't create extra tables for each subclass - your bat/bird tables wouldn't be used.

Secondly null columns are typically very lightweight. For example in postgres their is a bit mask on each row that says which columns are null. A bitmask indicates which columns are present, so adding a nullable column only adds 1bit per row (leaving aside some rounding up subtleties)

You basically have 4 choices:

- don't use STI (ie one table per model, with all of the attributes per model). You can still have a common base class (that must have `self.abstract_class = true) for any shared code
- use STI, with some columns unused for some subclasses
- use STI, but have your subclasses have a `has_one` relationship with a table that has extra columns for that particular subclass
- serialize the non shared attributes (ie as far as the db is concerned they do all have the same attributes)

There are valid cases for all of these - they have their drawbacks too. For example if you go down the has_one route you may find, dependant on use that you have a lot of queries to the extra table. On the other hands if you rarely use the extra attributes it's great.

I really wouldn't sweat a few null columns though - you're very unlikely to ever notice.

Answer (score 0):

For variadic fields you can use Rails [serialized attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html). If you want to select on them you can use [PostgreSQL HStore](https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore).